# Embedding Bold Small Caps

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, embedding

I am *required* to embed fonts in my document, in order to ensure the printing of my thesis goes well. The recommendation is to include `\usepackage{lmodern}`.
Unfortunately, my document uses bold small caps, which renders as bold lower case when I use `lmodern`.

(The thesis should look similar to the default template. Thus I can not use a completely different font)

(I currently use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, although I do not know if that is relevant)

How can I embed bold small caps?

MWE (removing `\usepackage{lmodern}` causes desired output):

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{sqp}{\textsc{sqp}}{sequential quadratic programming}
\newacronym{doe}{\textsc{d}o\textsc{e}}{design of experiments}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Acronyms ]

\section{Demo}
In text ok: \acrshort{doe} and \acrshort{sqp}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I included `lmodern` to ensure embedded fonts. 
This broke bold small caps.
When I removed `lmodern`, and checked if the fonts are embedded, this was the case. 
Thus I do not need the package, and I think my problem is solved.

Comment: Using a particular set of fonts, and embedding those fonts are two different things.  How would you achieve bold small caps *without* `\usepackage{lmodern}`?

Comment: I get bold small caps as the output for my glossary. Honestly, I do not know "How", so I am guessing there is some default behaviour somewhere.

Comment: Please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and tell us the main problem: Using bold small caps or embedding fonts. Currently this looks like [a XY-problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).

Comment: How do you get your glossary? We're going to need a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28808) if my previous link doesn't help

Comment: It's still not clear: Is your problem how to embed fonts or how to use bold small capitals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glossary in your example does not have **bold** small capitals but only small capitals. `lmodern` does not provide bold small capitals. So if you need to *use* bold small capitals you have to use a font, that provides them, e.g., Linux Libertine:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{sqp}{\textsc{sqp}}{sequential quadratic programming}
\newacronym{doe}{\textsc{d}o\textsc{e}}{design of experiments}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Acronyms ]

\section{Demo}
In text ok: \acrshort{doe} and \acrshort{sqp}
\end{document}
```

[image: example with Linux Libertine]

This is independent from how to *embed* fonts. But the default installations of TeX Live or MiKTeX will embed these fonts. You can check whether or not the fonts are embedded either using [`pdffonts`](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) or the font information dialog of a PDF viewer.

As an alternative you can use European Computer Modern (EC). It does also provide bold small caps:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{sqp}{\textsc{sqp}}{sequential quadratic programming}
\newacronym{doe}{\textsc{d}o\textsc{e}}{design of experiments}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Acronyms ]

\section{Demo}
In text ok: \acrshort{doe} and \acrshort{sqp}
\end{document}
```

[image: example with European Computer Modern]

But in this case you have to install [`cm-super`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) (if not already installed) to embed Type1 fonts into your document. If you are using Vanilla TeX Live the default installation does already have installed `cm-super`. If you are using the TeX Live of a Linux distribution you often have to install them (e.g., using `sudo apt-get install cm-super` if you are using debian linux) and if you are using MiKTeX you can install `cm-super` using the package manager.

Comment: I get lower case letters I the definitions when compiling on ShareLaTex. Before I added `\usepackage{lmodern}` I got the same output you show.

Comment: @user1380 Have a look at the changed answer.